# Not able to dynamically attach component to ag-grid which is read as viewContainerRef

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to attach one component dynamically as sibling to the ag-grid-angular. I have written an attribute directive which sits on top of the ag-grid and in the directive viewContainerRef is injected as below.

```
<ag-grid-angular tableDirective style="width: 100%;height:100%" class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData" [suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns]="true" [getContextMenuItems]="getContextMenuItems" [enableRangeSelection]="true" [rowClassRules]="rowClassRules"
                [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [suppressMakeColumnVisibleAfterUnGroup]="true" [rowGroupPanelShow]="rowGroupPanelShow" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [components]="components" [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
                [context]="context">
            </ag-grid-angular>
```

Inside of the directive I have a constructor like this.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'tableDirective'
})
class TableDirective(){

constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef){}

      attachComponent(component: any, options) {
         const toolTipComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver
          .resolveComponentFactory(component);
        this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(toolTipComponentFactory );
       }

}
```

I have a function to attach a component on some event of my choice. But I am not able to dynamically attach and If in case the component it is getting attached, Its attaching at some random place. Could someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am still using v22 of angular due to project limitations!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? on the first glance, applying directives to `ag-grid-angular` doesn't seem right. You probably should use functionality provided by ag-grid [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/components/), e.g. [tooltip](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-tooltip/)

Comment: I am trying to validate the values Entered in the cell. I am using host listeners in the directive and separating that part of the code. I am having a cell rendered in which I place a info icon on hover of which I need to show some error message.

Comment: https://blog.ag-grid.com/user-input-validation-with-ag-grid/ ?